# Error creating a new project with Unity 5.6.0f3, VRTK and SteamVR

Tags: unity-game-engine, vrtk

I have created a project from 0, import steamVR and followed the VRTK asset package, but at the time of playing I get the following error.

PlayerSettings Validation: Requested build target group (27) doesn't exist; #define symbols for scripting won't be added.
UnityEditor.PlayerSettings:SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(BuildTargetGroup, String)
VRTK.VRTK_Defines:EnsureVersionSymbolIsSet() (at Assets/VRTK/Scripts/Internal/VRTK_Defines.cs:60)
UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes()

Answer (score 0):

The VRTK asset package from the Asset store is not up to date in order to work with the latest version of Unity. That's why you are getting that error.

You have to install the latest version from Github which is actively updated. You can find the official SDK from 
[here](https://github.com/thestonefox/VRTK). Make sure to remove the old one first.

Comment: VRTK 3.2.0 is now on the Unity Asset Store since yesterday, it should be compatible with Unity 5.6

Comment: Well at-least this answer is not incorrect. Although what took you so long to do that because I've seen people having this problem in the past and they are all ignored.

Comment: Where did you see this problem raised in the past? I've checked the vrtk tag on stack overflow and I dont see any other questions on it. VRTK has also been compatible with Unity 5.6 for a long time if you used the github version. Going to the Unity Asset Store always takes longer because it has to be a tested release and approved by Unity. The slack channel for VRTK will generally point this out to people when they ask.

Comment: I've seen this few times on Unity answer.

Comment: Do you mean the Unity forums? I don't usually go on the Unity forums, if you do see people posting VRTK questions and have no answer then it would be awesome if you could redirect them to the Github issues, the vrtk slack channel or stack overflow, because I check these places for problems people are having.